# Some files lost their -x permission when import/ export in SVN

Tags: svn, import, export, tortoisesvn

I'm working in TortoiseSVN and i noticed some files (especially executable files like .sh) lost their -x permission when import/ export. There is some code, or SVN option to restore permissions or import/export these files without lose their permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.executable)

> On many operating systems, the ability to execute a file as a command
>   is governed by the presence of an execute permission bit. This bit
>   usually defaults to being disabled, and must be explicitly enabled by
>   the user for each file that needs it. But it would be a monumental
>   hassle to have to remember exactly which files in a freshly
>   checked-out working copy were supposed to have their executable bits
>   toggled on, and then to have to do that toggling. So, Subversion
>   provides the `svn:executable` property as a way to specify that the
>   executable bit for the file on which that property is set should be
>   enabled, and Subversion honors that request when populating working
>   copies with such files.

`svn:executable`

If present on a file, the client will make the file executable in Unix-hosted working copies.

Comment: thanks, i'm going to use this property... one more question, do you know why, if the execute permission bit was enabled, svn dissabled it? there is some internal protocol or is a way to protect the file? its just a doubt :)

Comment: @BrunoBuglioni - SVN just **doesn't store** this metadata from original filesystem